# C# create configuration file

Tags: c#-4.0

This code How can I create configuration file if so that i can change connection string easy

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Web;
using mshtml;


namespace tabcontrolweb
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

         }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string MyConString = "SERVER=192.168.0.78;" +
                 "DATABASE=webboard;" +
                 "UID=aimja;" +
                 "PASSWORD=aimjawork;" +
                 "charset=utf8;";
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
            MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            MySqlDataReader Reader;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT  urlwebboard FROM `listweb` WHERE `urlwebboard` IS NOT NULL AND ( `webbordkind` = 'เว็บท้องถิ่น' ) and `nourl`= 'n' order by province, amphore limit 4 ";
            connection.Open();
            Reader = command.ExecuteReader();


            string[] urls = new string[4];
            string thisrow = "";
            string sumthisrow = "";

            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                thisrow = "";

                for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    thisrow += Reader.GetValue(i).ToString();


                    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\file.txt", thisrow + " " + Environment.NewLine);
                    sumthisrow = Reader.GetValue(Reader.FieldCount - 1).ToString();

                }

                for (int m = 0; m < 4 ; m++)
                {
                    urls[m] = sumthisrow;
                    MessageBox.Show(urls[m]);          
                }

                webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(urls[0]));
                webBrowser1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                webBrowser2.Navigate(new Uri(urls[1]));
                webBrowser2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                webBrowser3.Navigate(new Uri(urls[2]));
                webBrowser3.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                webBrowser4.Navigate(new Uri(urls[3]));
                webBrowser4.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;


            }



            connection.Close();


        }



        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
            //{
            //    IHTMLDocument2 document = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
            //    if (document != null)
            //    {
            //        IHTMLSelectionObject currentSelection = document.selection;

            //        IHTMLTxtRange range = currentSelection.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;
            //        if (range != null)
            //        {
            //            const String search = "We";

            //            if (range.findText(search, search.Length, 2))
            //            {
            //                range.select();
            //            }
            //        }
            //    }
            //}
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create an XML configuration file looking like this :

```
<db-config>
    <server>192.168.0.78</server>
    <database>webboard</database>
    <...>...</...>
</db-config>
```

Then, use [XMLTextReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.aspx) to parse it.

Here is a basic example of how you can use it to parse XML files :

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
namespace ReadXMLfromFile
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Class1.
    /// </summary>
    class Class1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader ("books.xml");
            while (reader.Read()) 
            {
                switch (reader.NodeType) 
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an element.
                        Console.Write("<" + reader.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine(">");
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.Text: //Display the text in each element.
                        Console.WriteLine (reader.Value);
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.EndElement: //Display the end of the element.
                        Console.Write("</" + reader.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine(">");
                        break;
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Hint : Use the [ReadTofollowing()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162536.aspx) to get your values.

Once your XML DB Config Reader class is done, you use it each time you need a new connection, and you'll only need to change your DB Config XML file to change your DB Connections configuration.

Edit : there is an interesting article about [Storing database connection settings in .NET](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5779516.html) here.

Answer (score 2):

Use the default
[System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx)

that C# supports!

Answer (score 0):

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750.aspx